# MySQL Looking for a pattern of temperatures

Tags: mysql

Looking for a pattern of temperatures

Trying to produce a list of results from a simple table that records temperature and time every 5 minutes. The table only has two columns 'temp' and 'ttime'. The time is recorded as MySQL timestamp.

What I need to do is check for any patterns where the temperature goes over 40 for more than two hours within a 24 hour period using just the data from same table and there are thousands of rows of data.

**Quick sample of data:**

| temp | ttime |
| --- | --- |
| 35 | 2022-08-14 12:05:00 |
| 40 | 2022-08-14 12:10:00 |
| 41 | 2022-08-14 12:15:00 |
| 37 | 2022-08-14 12:20:00 |

Not sure how to even start something like this.

Comment: How does the data get filled? Keeping track of a timestamp as soon as the threshold is reached is easier in a programming language, otherwise you probably have to write a loop query to check for each timestamp if it is still above the threshold and as soon as the time value between when it first went above 40 and the timestamp where you analyzed is more than 2h. I find loops in any language easier than sql

Comment: At the minute the data is coming from a CSV file. The rest of the work is being done in PHP, I was just hoping there may be a way to do it directly in MySQL instead of loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like

```
SELECT * FROM data d1
 WHERE temp >= 40 
   AND temp >= ALL (
       SELECT temp FROM d2 
        WHERE d2.ttime BETWEEN 
                 date_add(d1.ttime, INTERVAL -2 HOUR)
                 AND d1.ttime
   );
```

to get the first record after two hours higher than 40 degrees (can't verify at the moment)